# Codeigniter: Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I use codeigniter as cms framework, if database hostname is localhost, it works correctly.

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = 'test';
$db['default']['database'] = 'jinma';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
```

Using above configuration works correctly, but if hostname is changed to:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '192.168.1.222';
```

A Database Error Occurred:

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
Filename: third_party/fuel/Loader.php
Line Number: 134
```

and i can ssh 192.168.1.222,
Meanwhile in 192.168.1.222, it's also ok when hostname is localhost.

I searched in google and got a solution to add:

```
$db['default']['port'] = '3306';
```

but it doesn't work for me, any idea?

Thank you, this is my first question, sorry to be stupid.

Comment: Did u upload your db to 192.168.1.222?

Comment: Yes, i can run my website locally in 192.168.1.222, and configuration is $db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As default a MySQL Server is configured that he allowes only a binding from localhost.

Go to your **my.cnf** and comment the line

```
bind 127.0.0.1
```

Then you should look that your MySQL user has enough rights to access from other ips.

[MySQL Remote Access](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html)

Comment: Hi Stony, I think your answer works for me, but unfortunately I can't find my my.cnf, i have been using 'find / -name my.cnf', the result is empty( I used macport to install mysql5), so what should I do now?

Comment: You could look with ps fax in your processlist perhaps you can see on the mysql process which file is loaded.