# CodeIgniter error- unable to connect to database using the provided settings

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new to PHP and CodeIgniter  and I am trying to fetch data from a mysql table using MVC pattern of codeIgniter.

My model class is:

```
<?php

class News_Model extends CI_Model
{

    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_news($id)
    {
        if($id!=FALSE)
        {
            $query= $this->db->get_where('news', array('id' => $id));
            return $query->row_array();
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }   
    }

}


 ?>
```

and my database.php file is:

```
  $active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'user';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['port'] = '3306';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

But when I run my file, it shows the following error:

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: C:\wamp\www\codeignite\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 124
```

My mysql is up and running but still i am not able to figure out the cause for this error.

Comment: What does Line Number 124 say?

Comment: Try checking the port

Comment: Is your database named `user`?

Comment: The port is fine. I am able to connect with this port using my java application.

Comment: did you bind port with your localhost check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795300/codeigniter-unable-to-connect-to-your-database-server-using-the-provided-settin

Comment: certainly there is problem with database.php, check the values you are providing again.

Comment: use mysqli as db driver. mysql is deprecated...

Comment: have you tried setting localhost to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Is your host, localhost ? I meant isn't a remote server ? if it is then isnt' localhost, also check your dbname, the user (seems root without password), and your port etc.

Comment: Check my answer for proper debugging: Knowing something about the connection error is going to help.

Comment: switch on debugging in root folders index.php or via config and I would autoload the databse if is used

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just for debugging your problem:

Go to `system/database/mysql/mysql_driver` and in `db_connect` method delete the @ from `@mysql_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, TRUE);`

That will show you what is wrong with the ddbb connection, and you'll now what is the problem. 
After that, post the MySQL server error.

Answer (score 1):

First debug your database connection using this script at the end of database.php

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($db['default']);
echo '</pre>';
```

Or you can change

> $db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE; --> $db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;

in /application/config/database.php

Comment: 1) It's hardcoded, printing the array won't do any debug, nothing is going to change those hardcoded values; 2) if you can't even connect, what's the point of setting on or off a permanent connection?

Comment: @DamienPirsy I think it has to do with the DB location/pooling. My local SQL Express in a demo project seemed to fail with Codeigniter, but worked on a direct connection string. Setting pconnect to False cleared it up.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it is a copy paste error or it really matters on your problem but you have only one underscore at the model constructor.

You should try it like that

```
 public function __construct()
```

*I know this could be a comment but I can't comment (yet).*

Answer (score 1):

Please set username and password for file `database.php` on hosting, it's ok.

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'abaccc';
$db['default']['password'] = 'abaccc123';
$db['default']['database'] = 'abaccc';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

Answer (score 1):

Just run your mysql server. i have an error like that. and i run my mysql server, if you are already installed it, please go to services -> mysql/mysqld/mysql2/

or anything like mysql.. select automatic and start.